# Android Studio Manifest error

Tags: android, manifest

I have imported a project and I am finding error in Android Manifest file. As I am new to Android Studio Please Help me to Correct the error. These are the lines I'm facing error. This is my Manifest file and in the 1st 5 lines I am having error. Please help me to correct the error

```
 <manifest xmlns:"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
android:versionCode="16" android:versionName="2.18"
android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.Vinformax.VinformaxAR"
platformBuildVersionCode="24" platformBuildVersionName="7.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:label="0x7f030000" android:icon="0x7f020000" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="false">
    <activity android:label="0x7f030000" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="0x7f030000" android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.ti.s3d" android:required="false" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.osterhoutgroup.api.ext" android:required="false" />
</application>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="20000" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: what are the error ?

Comment: what error you faced ??

Comment: why there is a * in android:theme name

Comment: recommended https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

First, [`manifest` does not have an `android:theme` attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html).

Second, any `android:theme` attribute will not have an `*` in its value.

Most likely, your `android:theme` should be on the `<application>` element, or perhaps a specific `<activity>` element, and the value should be `"@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`.

Comment: @KaminiIshwarya: Delete the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` from the `<manifest>` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: I have changed it, but no use, I am still having error